# How to get an array with specific index outside the foreach in Php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, console, display

My problem was to get the array employeeIds in an array outside a foreach

`$jobCard`

$jobCard contains an associative in my instance I get the employee_id in the array

```
$employeeId = array();  

foreach ($jobCards as $jobCard) {
    $employeeId[] = $jobCard['employee_id'];
}

$employees = Employee::LoadArray($employeeId); 

foreach ($employees as $employeeID => $Employee) {
    $employeeName[$employeeID] = $Employee->getName();
    Console::Log('name', $employeeName);
}

foreach ($jobCards as $jobCard) {
    Console::Log('$employeeName', $employeeName);
    $notes[] = $employeeName[$employeeID] . " \n" .$jobCard['description_notes'];
}

$detail['notes'] = implode("\n", $notes);
Console::Log('display', $detail);
```

Comment: sure about this part `employeeId = array();` missing the `$`

Comment: Hard to decipher!, Can you edit the question and give it a try to make it more understandable?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed $ when copied on my end.

Thanks for responding. My problem was to get  $employeeId[] array outside the foreach

Comment: Where u didn't get $employeeId, check by putting print_r($employeeId) after it assigned and check after passing to other function thats first line of LoadArray($employeeId), is Getting value

Comment: @Rasa the value of $employeeId has 1 associative array with these value


`array (
  0 => '13',
  1 => '18',
  2 => '13',
)`

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear because we do not have a [mcve].  Needs Debugging Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want employee names for ids combined with the description notes. If so, then your iteration logic is a bit mixed up.

A simpler way is to:

1. get all employees
2. iterate `$jobCards` and compile the note while looking up the employee name in the employees array

E.g.:

```
<?php
// get all employees for the collected ids
$employees = Employee::LoadArray(array_column($jobCards, 'employee_id'));

// map job cards to notes
$notes = array_map(function ($jobCard) use($employees) {
    return sprintf(
        "%s\n%s",
        // access the employee name directly
        $employees[$jobCard['employee_id']]->getName(),
        $jobCard['description_notes']
    );
}, $jobCards);

$detail['notes'] = implode("\n", $notes);
```

function reference:

[`array_column`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.array-column.php), 
[`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php)